Нужно чтобы изображение увеличивалось на моб. устройстве, планшете. Bootstrap5
Делаю карту товара. Нужно чтобы картинка увеличивалась на мобильном устройстве, планшете и т.д (кроме больших экранов, ПК, ноутбук). Делаю на Bootstrap. Как это сделать?
На пк товары будут располагаться в строку по 4 элемента.



        <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Букеты</h5>
            </div>
            <img src="source/images/k1.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Выбрать  ➞</a>
            </div>
          </div>         
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">
          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Композиции</h5>
            </div>
            <img src="source/images/k6.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Выбрать  ➞</a>
            </div>
          </div>         
        </div>




по фрагменту данного кода не совсем понятно что сдерживает картинку по ширине. Может ограничение блока, может какие то стили для картинки, может размер самой картинки. Если есть возможность дополните код стилями что бы сам код исполнялся.

У вас там написано width: 18rem, возможно он ограничивает ширину. Также убедитесь, что у вас в img  есть стили max-width: 100% и height: auto

но думаю всё же width 18rem мешает, так как текст центрирован относительно картинки, а значит с картинкой всё ок
